# How do I set a custom UIView to the navigation item's titleView and have it properly size?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a custom `UIView`. Dead simple, just always wants to be 300x30 if possible.

```
class MyVoo: UIView {
    override func sizeThatFits(size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 300, height: 30)
    }
}
```

I then set it to the `navigationItem`'s `titleView` property like so:

```
let voo = MyVoo()
voo.backgroundColor = .magentaColor()
navigationItem.titleView = voo
voo.sizeToFit()
```

But when I run it, it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see width is weird. It's set to 246 for some reason, which is just slightly too much and causes the back button text to be cut off. I don't mind it being cut off, but it should occupy the space to the left better, or be the proper size and allow the back button text to show.

Basically my question is: how do I have this custom `UIView` be properly sized in the navigation bar? Right now it's very clearly "off", and I'd like it to effectively behave as if I just `navigationItem.title` (instead of `titleView`) to 300px worth of text. Properly shortened, the back button has proper text, etc. Rather than this weird solution where it's not properly sized for anything at all. How do I properly size it and how does it decide its sizing?